# Is there a way to use bitbucket to fork a subversion project?

Tags: svn, mercurial, sourceforge, bitbucket

I have commit rights to a sourceforge project that is owned by the other, primary developer. I'd like to manage my own changes using mercurial, and in fact I'd like to publish them as a fork of this project on bitbucket. However, I want to be able to easily push changes back to the main subversion project; this won't be a hostile fork, just a different path.

Does bitbucket support the svn extensions to Mercurial? If so, how can I use them to fork a sourceforge project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hgsubversion` is **the only** tool you need to keep in sync the main Sourceforge svn repo and your Bitbucket hg fork. No special support for forking using it is required from Bitbucket.

Basically, after installing `hgsubversion` and creating an empty repo for your fork of the project `foo` at Bitbucket you need to this:

```
$ hg clone https://foo.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/foo
$ cd foo
$ hg push https://bitbucket.org/offby1/foo
```

Then you can use normal `push`, `pull`, `in` and `out` hg commands on both hg and svn repos.

Comment: Beware: hgsubversion has some pretty severe bugs. See https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issue/155/hgsubversion-does-not-convert-certain-tags for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two: [hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home), and [hgsvn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hgsvn). I might prefer the former, but maybe there are features in one that you need.

Comment: As per my question, I'm aware of the existence of the extensions, what I'm interested in is whether bitbucket supports forking using those.